# Variables empty after inner loop

Tags: bash, variables

i have an issue with my bash script

```
t='Hostname\cfg;'

echo "Header" > $DST

for i in *
do
        t="$i;"
        egrep -v "(^$|^#)" $IPLIST | while read ii
        do  
                if grep -q "$ii" $i
                then
                        t=$t"y;"
                else
                        t=$t"n;"
                fi  
echo "$t"
        done

echo "x$t"

        n=$(($n + 1))
        echo "$n"

        #echo "$ii;$t" # >> $DST
        #t=""
done
```

Produces the following output:

```
h0010001.conf;y;
h0010001.conf;y;y;
<ommited>
h0010001.conf;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;n;n;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;n;y;y;y;y;y;y;n;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;y;n;n;
xh0010001.conf;
```

So for some reason the t Variable is empty after the inner loop has completed.
What I want to achieve is, to write t - after the second loop into a file.

Comment: Commands in a pipeline are executed in a subshell, so variable assignments don't affect the original shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Barmar was spot on. Here's a typical workaround.

Change the while loop to run in the parent shell:

```
while read ii
    do  
            if grep -q "$ii" $i
            then
                    t=$t"y;"
            else
                    t=$t"n;"
            fi  
            echo "$t"
    done < <(egrep -v "(^$|^#)" $IPLIST)
```

Comment: Though, the external `egrep` is completely useless.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that's immaterial to the question, but yes, there are many things I'd write different here

Comment: In fact it is somehow related, because if the OP hadn't used this `egrep` and had filtered directly using globs, the question would have never arised!

Comment: He's asking about the reason why his variable "didn't stick". He could avoid having the problem in many many (unrelated) ways.