# bash shell builtin "read" not working as expected

Tags: bash

These are the commands:

```
$ echo $LINE

$ echo TEXT
TEXT
$ echo TEXT | read LINE
$ echo $LINE

$
```

I would expect "echo "$LINE" to return "TEXT", but its empty.
Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a near-duplicate of ["Bash variable scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124167), ["variable reset in a bash script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086376), ["Variables empty after inner loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655013), ["Why does my Bash counter reset after while loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006229), and many others. See [BashFAQ #24: "I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes create a subshell, and a variable created in a subshell does not exist in the main environment.

You can do:

```
$ read line < <(echo 'my text')
$ echo "$line"
my text
```